# Implementing an interface without implementing it

Tags: java, inheritance

Can implement an interface without implementing it-- as in:

```
interface A { void m2(); }

class B { public void m2() { ... } } 

class C extends B implements A { ... /* no implementation of m2() here */ }
```

What i'm wondering is, is there a way to force the descendant class, class `C` here, to implement the method `m2()`?

This looks a bit sideways-- breaking the expected chain in inheritance.

There can be cases i can't think of now where it would be necessary to force the subclass in this fashion.

TIA.

//==========================

EDIT: one scenario:

There is a class `B` and an interface `A` developed in two different places in the application with a method `m2()` having the same signature in both.

`B` is implementing `m2()` in its own way-- without even knowing what `A` is all about.

when `C` above gets quickly in, it has an `m2()` that has nothing to do with the contract in `A`.

This takes poor management of development. but, still.

//=================================

EDIT-2:

Restricting m2()-of-B's access to package level or `protected` works. 
This way, `m2()` of `B` that `C` is inheriting won't do for that of `A` since it isn't `public`.

This is a bit of tempering with what a class should do in itself-- but then it isn't.
A super-class should be able to direct a sub this much. loosely similar to the use of `final` on methods or on the class itself. Note AndyThomas's useful ans. though.

Comment: Can you identify a scenario where this would be an issue?  Surely all that matters is that `C` obeys the contract promised by `A`.

Comment: "What i'm wondering is, is there a way to force the descendant class, class C here, to implement the method m2()? " Yes, directly implement `A`. When you extend `B` you already stick to the contract.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth special attention to "wondering" there. it's a tool if it exists. although i dont think there's some such stuff.

Comment: *"There can be cases i can't think of now"* If you can't even think of a case, why stress so much over it? I can't think of a good use for something like this..

Comment: A concrete example of a contract incompatibility which prevents correct implementation, is the `List` and the `Set` interfaces - their `equals()` and `hashCode()` have incompatible contracts. You cannot have a class `MySetLikeList extends ArrayList implements Set` which correctly behaves as a List and a Set wrt equality. As noted in the answers, the compiler cannot prevent anyone from doing it anyway.

Comment: ...if there is a way to _force_...  Always a bad start to an API design.  As Paul Graham said, "Surely a library that _lets_ you do X is at least as powerful as a library that forces you to do X."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written, class C must satisfy both the contracts for `B.m2()` and `A.m2()`.

Those contracts are either compatible or not.

**If those contracts are compatible,** then `B.m2()` is either a sufficient implementation for C or not.

- If it is sufficient, an override is not required.
- If it is *not* sufficient, then it is the responsibility of class C to override it.

  - Inside class C, you can force an override by ... simply overriding the method.
  - Outside class C, you cannot force C to override an existing, non-abstract superclass method.

**If those contracts are *not* compatible,** then C cannot both extend B and implement A. In this case, you could use composition instead of inheritance -- have C implement A, and include a B in its representation.

There is no mechanism in Java to force all instantiable classes implementing an interface to *override* superclass implementations of methods in the interface.  You can, however, force all instantiable classes to implement an `abstract` method somewhere in their inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: is this from a source or your own? useful stuff

Comment: I wrote this answer. It relies partly on the *Liskov substitution principle* -- if C extends B, it must be possible to replace B instances with C instances, and C must therefore satisfy the contracts of B.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare class B to be abstract it wouldn't be required to implement m2 and therefore C (by inheriting B) would be required to:

```
abstract class B implements A {}
```

Comment: Sure, if you completely change the OP's code, it will behave differently.